# Calendar java does not work properly

Tags: java, date, calendar

```
import java.util.Calendar;

...

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(new Date(1443351600000L));// set to 2015-9-27
calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23); // add 23 hours
```

I don't know why calendar is updated from `2015-09-27 00:00:00` to `2015-09-28 00:00:00`. I expect `2015-09-27 23:00:00`.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(new Date(1443351600000L));// set to 2015-9-28
calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23); // add 23 hours
```

And this one works fine. The result is `2015-09-28 23:00:00`.

Comment: **Day light savings** change probably? Which timezone are you on?

Comment: *"Calendar java does not work properly"* ... It is more than a little presumptuous to assume that a code base that has been maintained and optimized for over 10 years must be the cause of behavior that you can't explain.  In such a case, it is much more likely that you just don't understand the basis for the behavior.

Comment: You've noticed that both codes are the same?

Comment: @Tom yes, setTime() gets the same value both times so one comment is wrong

Comment: Instead of coming up with the millis for a particular date, the right way would be `calendar.clear(); calendar.set(2015, Calendar.SEPTEMBER, 27);`. That way we don't have to verify that the millis are, what it is claimed to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's only 23 hours in the day if [Daylight Saving Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) starts on `2015-9-27`.

Google search says the following starts Daylight Saving Time on Sep 27, 2015:

- [New Zealand](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/new-zealand/auckland)
- [Samoa](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/samoa/apia)
- [South Pole](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/antarctica/south-pole)

If you're in one of these places, there's your answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are right. I just realized this last night.